# How to fix warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char'

Tags: c

warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    char name;
    printf("Enter your Name\n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Your name is = %s\n",name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Declare the variable name as a character array.

Answer (score 1):

The warning mentioned in the question refers to the following line:

`printf("Your name is = %s\n",name);`

The `%s` format specifer requires you to pass a string (i.e. a `char *`) as an additional parameter, but you are passing a single `char` instead. However, the problem in your program is not in that line, but rather in the declaration of `name`.

The declaration

`char name;`

only declares a single character. If you want to store a name consisting of several characters, you must create an array of characters, for example like this:

`char name[50];`

After changing this declaration, you should change your program to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    char name[50];

    printf( "Enter your Name\n" );
    scanf( "%49s", name );

    printf( "Your name is = %s\n", name );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and why did you add %49s in scanf? and also if I would have used %c instead %s that would have stored a single character but %s is know for storing multiple characters

Comment: @Vyomanaut: The `%49s` will limit the number of characters written into the array to 49 characters plus the terminating null character (50 in total). If you don't add this, then there will be no limit, so if the user enters more than 49 characters, you will have a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), which will probably overwrite important parts of your program, possibly causing your program to crash or misbehave in other ways.

Comment: @Vyomanaut: You could have used `char name;` with the `%c` format specifier too. That is correct. However, as you correctly stated, that would only have stored and printed a single character, not several characters.